# Why does my function write to file not write to file when combined with a combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have narrowed it down to that i believe it is my write to file function. when i run the program and add an instance it does not even write anything to the designated file.

i am trying to figure out how to select an item from the combobox and then have the following textbox next to it add its information into the correct place in the file.

here is the code i have so far:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class frmSemseter_Project_ll
    Dim ComicArray() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Comics.txt")

    Private Sub frmSemseter_Project_ll_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dgvComics.DataSource = ComicArray.ToList
        DisplayComicData(dgvComics, "Comics.txt")
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuFile_Exit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuFile_Exit.Click
        'Closes the program
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayComicData(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, filename As String)
        dgvComics.Refresh()
        If IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
            Dim query = From Line In IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
                        Let Title = Line.Split(","c)(0)
                        Let Issue = Line.Split(","c)(1)
                        Let Publisher = Line.Split(","c)(2)
                        Let CoverDate = Line.Split(","c)(3)
                        Let CoverPrice = FormatCurrency(Line.Split(","c)(4))
                        Let AddedDate = Line.Split(","c)(5)
                        Order By Title Ascending
                        Select Title, Issue, Publisher, CoverDate, CoverPrice, AddedDate
            dgvComics.DataSource = query.ToList()
        ElseIf Not IO.File.Exists("Comics.txt") Then
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Please Insert the Comics File.", "No File",
                                                          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuSort_Ascending_Title_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSort_Ascending_Title.Click
        Dim query = From Line In ComicArray
                    Let Title = Line.Split(","c)(0)
                    Let Issue = Line.Split(","c)(1)
                    Let Publisher = Line.Split(","c)(2)
                    Let CoverDate = Line.Split(","c)(3)
                    Let CoverPrice = FormatCurrency(Line.Split(","c)(4))
                    Let AddedDate = Line.Split(","c)(5)
                    Order By Title Ascending
                    Select Title, Issue, Publisher, CoverDate, CoverPrice, AddedDate
        dgvComics.DataSource = query.ToList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuSort_Desending_Title_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSort_Desending_Title.Click
        Dim query = From Line In ComicArray
                    Let Title = Line.Split(","c)(0)
                    Let Issue = Line.Split(","c)(1)
                    Let Publisher = Line.Split(","c)(2)
                    Let CoverDate = Line.Split(","c)(3)
                    Let CoverPrice = FormatCurrency(Line.Split(","c)(4))
                    Let AddedDate = Line.Split(","c)(5)
                    Order By Title Descending
                    Select Title, Issue, Publisher, CoverDate, CoverPrice, AddedDate
        dgvComics.DataSource = query.ToList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuSort_Ascending_Issue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSort_Ascending_Issue.Click
        Dim query = From Line In ComicArray
            Let Title = Line.Split(","c)(0)
            Let Issue = Line.Split(","c)(1)
            Let Publisher = Line.Split(","c)(2)
            Let CoverDate = Line.Split(","c)(3)
            Let CoverPrice = FormatCurrency(Line.Split(","c)(4))
            Let AddedDate = Line.Split(","c)(5)
            Order By Issue Ascending
            Select Title, Issue, Publisher, CoverDate, CoverPrice, AddedDate
        dgvComics.DataSource = query.ToList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mnuSort_Desending_Issue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnuSort_Desending_Issue.Click
        Dim query = From Line In ComicArray
            Let Title = Line.Split(","c)(0)
            Let Issue = Line.Split(","c)(1)
            Let Publisher = Line.Split(","c)(2)
            Let CoverDate = Line.Split(","c)(3)
            Let CoverPrice = FormatCurrency(Line.Split(","c)(4))
            Let AddedDate = Line.Split(","c)(5)
            Order By Issue Descending
            Select Title, Issue, Publisher, CoverDate, CoverPrice, AddedDate
        dgvComics.DataSource = query.ToList()
    End Sub

'Everything works fine until this point
'from here through the whole write to file function does not seem to be working 
'whenever i click the add button that i made it does not even add the values into the file

    Private Sub btnAddComic_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddComic.Click
        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Title" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Title")
        End If

        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Issue" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Issue")
        End If

        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Publisher" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Publisher")
        End If

        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Cover Date" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Cover Date")
        End If

        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Cover Price" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Cover Price")
        End If

        If cbComicAdder.SelectedText = "Added Date" Then
            WriteToFile("Comics.txt", CStr(txtComicAdder.Text), "Added Date")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub WriteToFile(ByVal filename As String, ByVal Item As String, ByVal Instance As String)
        Dim sw As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.AppendText(filename)
        While CBool(Instance)
            If Instance = "Title" Then
                sw.Write(Item & ",")
            ElseIf Instance = "Issue" Then
                sw.Write(Item & ",")
            ElseIf Instance = "Publisher" Then
                sw.Write(Item & ",")
            ElseIf Instance = "Cover Date" Then
                sw.Write(Item & ",")
            ElseIf Instance = "Cover Price" Then
                sw.Write(Item & ",")
            ElseIf Instance = "Added Date" Then
                sw.Write(Item)
            End If
        End While
        sw.Close()
    End Sub

'how can i fix this function so that it will work?

    Private Sub btnRefreshGrid_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefreshGrid.Click
        dgvComics.ClearSelection()
        dgvComics.Refresh()
        dgvComics.Update()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I only read 12 characters/ -1

Comment: well im trying to get help and no one seems like they are able to

Comment: GENIUS! THAT MUST BE IT! NOBODY IS ABLE TO!

Comment: BTW CAPS LOCK IS CRUISE CONTROL FOR COOL

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PLEASE HELP

Comment: thanks i guess i didnt know how ask the question im editing it now

Comment: Out of curiosity. Did you try to compile this code? CBool("Added date") ?????

Comment: yes, it compiles fine and runs smoothly

Comment: I suggest to put a breakpoint at the first line of the button click event, then follow step by step what your code is doing. I will bet that converting the string Instance to a Bool doesn't run smoothly

Comment: o thanks i didnt even think of a class, we just covered them in class, and yea steave you were right i put in a breakpoint and it didnt run through it at all but it just made it seem like it ran. but now the write function is not running

Comment: If I am right you need only to remove the While loop leaving only the internal ifs and your function will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example Class version

```
Public Class Comic
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Issue As Integer

    ' etc

    Public Sub SaveData
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(yourFileNameHere)

            sr.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, ...{n}", 
                  Title, Issue, Publisher, IssueDate, SoForth, SoOn)

        End Using
    End Sub
```

The string describes the format or layout which is mainly the `,` then the data to write.

If your app relies on the user to fill in and save fields one at a time, that may prove to be problematic.  Before saving, the class could check to see if all the info is there to prevent partial records being written.

Comment: the other part can use it too - read the file into a `List(of Comic)` and it as the datasource (or use a BindingList).  if you read onle line at a time, you could feed that to the Comic's constructor and let it seed the props itself